# How can compare two date type DATE using filter in tmap

Tags: talend

I have two tables contains the same columns
[image]

So I want to compare two date EVENT_TIME type DATE

***The error is:  The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) java.util.Date, java.util.Date***

Any help please

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "compareTo".
Replace the following code in expression:

```
row2.EVENT_TIME.compareTo(out1.EVENT_TIME)<0 || row2.EVENT_TIME.compareTo(out1.EVENT_TIME)==0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use date difference function and make sure you convert to long as the result of the function is in long data type,

```
TalendDate.diffDate(date1, date2)
```

In your case its,

```
TalendDate.diffDate(row2.EVENT_TIME, out1.EVENT_TIME) <= 0.longValue()
```